# IBM MQ - JMeter - How to obtain the MQMD CorrelationID/Message ID

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mq

My requirement is for implement a method where JMeter can check that the messages appearing in the consumer queue match up to messages that have been sent from JMeter. The script I have implemented works as expected, i.e. the messages are appearing in the corresponding consumer queue.

I understand the required methods to perform this can be found within either the following classes: MQPutMessageOptions or MQMD. I implemented the following, which generates a Correlation ID. However, I understood that MQ would create a system generated correlation ID in the MQMD header. Has anyone worked with this classes in order to obtain this information?

```
    import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions
    import com.ibm.mq.MQC
    import com.ibm.mq.MQMD
    import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage
    
    def producer=vars.getObject("Producer")
    def session=vars.getObject("SenderSession")
    def msg=vars.getObject("Message")
    
    //def myCorrelationID = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace('-','').substring(0,24)
    
    //def putMsg = new com.ibm.mq.MQMessage()
    msg.format = "MQSTR"
    
    int putOpenOpts = MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT | MQPMO_NEW_MSG_ID | MQPMO_NEW_CORREL_ID
    
    
    
    putMsg.characterSet = 1208
    putMsg.priority = 2
    putMsg.correlationId = myCorrelationID.getBytes()
    putMsg.messageId = myCorrelationID.getBytes()
        
    log.info("jms-client sent:" + myCorrelationID)
    //def mqpmo = new MQPutMessageOptions()
    //int putOptions = MQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT | MQC.MQPMO_NEW_MSG_ID | MQC.MQPMO_NEW_CORREL_ID
    //mqpmo.getJMQIStructure()
    
    //mqpmo.Options = MQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT | MQC.MQPMO_NEW_MSG_ID | MQC.MQPMO_NEW_CORREL_ID
    //msg.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace('-','').substring(0,24));
    
    // Priority: 4 - default JMS 1.1 priority. 
    // Expiry: 0 - never expire
    if("${persistent}".equals("true")){
        producer.send(msg,javax.jms.DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT,4,0)
    } else {
        producer.send(msg,javax.jms.DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT,4,0)
    }
    
    if("${transacted}".equals("true")) session.commit()
    
    SampleResult.setResponseData(msg.toString())
    SampleResult.setDataType(org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.TEXT)
```

Receiver thread group:

```
    import com.ibm.mq.MQC
    import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions
    
    def consumer=vars.getObject("Consumer")
    def session=vars.getObject("ReceiverSession")
    def msg = consumer.receive("${receive_timeout}" as Integer)
    
    if(msg!=null) {
        if("${transacted}".equals("true")) session.commit()
        
        log.debug("########### Message Received"+msg)
    
        SampleResult.setResponseData(msg.toString())
        SampleResult.setDataType(org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.TEXT)
        
    } else {
        log.info("############ consumer.receive timed out (timeout value: " + "${receive_timeout}" + ")")
        //Mark timeout as 'error' to enable filtering out in listeners (to just analyse successful receive rate etc)
        SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
    }
```

Groovy isn't my forte. It would be helpful if someone could point me in the direction of what method needs to be implemented in the receiver thread group that would check the system generated CorrelationID.

Objective:

- Obtain the system generated CorrelationID from the sender thread group
- Periodically check consumer queue and cross-check the CorrelationID from one of the messages and confirm it was sent from the sender thread group

Thank you.

---

Update 07/06
I tried the following:

- I added Dmitri's solution to the publisher thread group. There were no issues published the message to the queue.
- I added receiver thread group solution as follows:

  def consumer=vars.getObject("Consumer")
  def session=vars.getObject("ReceiverSession")
  def msg=consumer.receive("${receive_timeout}" as Integer)
  def queueOptions=new MQGetMessageOptions()

  queueOptions.options=MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT
  queueOptions.matchOptions=MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID

  def response = new MQMessage()
  response.correlationId = props.put('correlation_id_' + ctx.getThreadNum())
  queue.get(response, queueOptions)

But that returned the following error after running 3 iterations with a single user. There were 8 messages in the queue.

[image: JMeter Error]

I also tried using the following in the Publisher thread group:

```
def mqmd=new com.ibm.mq.MQMD()
def pmo=new com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions()

pmo.options = MQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT | MQC.MQPMO_NEW_MSG_ID | MQC.MQPMO_NEW_CORREL_ID

// Priority: 4 - default JMS 1.1 priority. 
// Expiry: 0 - never expire
if("${persistent}".equals("true")){
    producer.send(mqmd,pmo,msg,javax.jms.DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT,4,0)
} else {
    producer.send(mqmd,pmo,msg,javax.jms.DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT,4,0)
}
```

[image]

This is the response of a successful message:

[image]

But that JMSMessageID doesn't match for the same message when retrieving it from the queue. I tested this by clearing down all of the queues. So there was only a single message to be retrieved by the consumer thread group. Does anyone know why they don't match?

Comment: Not sure I am certain which questions you are asking. If you are asking when MQ generates a CorrelID, it does so if you ask with the MQPMO_NEW_CORREL_ID option. If you're asking where it puts said ID so you can retrieve it, it is in the MQMessage.correlationid - the same one you are putting your own generated correl ID into. You can't have both your own one and MQ's generated one. Is that what you are asking? If not, can you add some more specific questions to your post.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the [JMS Point-to-Point](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point) component? Then correlation of the response is done automatically by JMeter.

Comment: Hi @MoragHughson. I was looking for the answer to your second statement. What I have in the code at the moment was to try something out. But I actually need what you have mentioned, which is the MQ generated correlation ID.

Comment: Hi @DanielSteinmann - I wasn't sure where to get the QueueConnectionFactory and JNDI properties from. When I tried putting the host, port and other details within the JNDI properties section, the connection would fail.

Comment: You need configure JNDI resources first, see [Configuring JMS and Jakarta Messaging resources](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=configuring-jms-jakarta-messaging-resources).

Comment: Do you have all you need from my comment to achieve this now or are you missing some details on how to do it?

Comment: @SachinPatel: There is also a [Sample JMeter Test Plan for MQ JMS](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mqperf/tree/gh-pages/jmeter) provided by IBM.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann - that is the template I have been using. The difference with that template is that is purely send and receiving messages to/from the queues. I have been working on customising it to fit the requirement of sending the message, obtaining the correlation ID of that message, then checking the corresponding Correlation ID for the message appears in the consumer thread group. What I have noticed though is that I cannot use the JMSCorrelationID. It has to be the MQPMO correlationID. As I understand that remains the same for the message throughout the journey.

Comment: @MoragHughson - I am going to try your implementation today. I will let you know how I get on and post the code, if it works successfully.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't post code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)
2. Dont't use JMeter Functions or Variables like `${transacted}` as only first occurrence will be cached and used in subsequent iterations, see [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation for details.
3. I fail to see where do you declare or obtain `myCorrelationID` in the "Receiver thread group"
4. Instead of consuming messages blindly you can ask the queue to give you the message with the given correlation id, however it's better to check how the real consumer will be getting the messages from the queue.

So you should do something like:

- In publisher thread group:

  ```
   props.put('correlation_id_' + ctx.getThreadNum(), putMsg.correlationId)
  ```
- In receiver thread group:

  ```
   def queueOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions()
   queueOptions.options = CMQC.MQGMO_WAIT | CMQC.MQGMO_CONVERT
   queueOptions.matchOptions = CMQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID
   def response = new MQMessage()
   response.correlationId = props.put('correlation_id_' + ctx.getThreadNum())       
   queue.get(response, queueOptions)
  ```

More information:

- [Getting a particular message](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=queue-getting-particular-message)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance Dmitri. 

The publisher thread group works and posts a message to the queue. However the receiver thread group is throwing the following error:

javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Properties.put() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [correlation_id_0]
Possible solutions: put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), get(java.lang.Object), get(java.lang.Object), plus(java.util.Map), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)